# NodeJS File System

Tags: node.js

modified an internal JSON file Object property via NodeJS File System through a dropdown on the UI and then when I read it again for further modification, the earlier modified value is not there. When I open the JSON file I can see the modified value but when I read the same file via 'fs.readfile' method, I debug it and I get to see the original value instead of the modified one.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this ?

I am calling this method from the respective place to read the file first and then write to it. This will be called from a separate module.

```
fileOperation: async function (operation, fileName, dataToWrite) {
switch (operation) {
  case 'read':
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../location/' + fileName), function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err)
        } else {
          const parsedData= JSON.parse(data);
          return resolve(parsedData);
        }
      })
    });
  case 'write':
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../location/' + fileName), JSON.stringify(dataToWrite), {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        } else {
          return resolve('File written successfully');
        }
      });
    })
}
```

And on the index.js file, this one:

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, './location/fileName'), function (err, data) {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).send(err);
} else {
  fileData = JSON.parse(data).requiredKey;
}
```

The fileData above is not the one that I saved earlier.

Calling the methods from this switch case:

```
case 'dropdownSelection':
      this.fileOperation('read', 'file.json', {}).then(fileData => {
        fileData.key = updatedData;
        this.fileOperation('write', 'file.json', fileData).then(success => {
          return resolve(success);
        }).catch(error => {
          return reject(error)
        })
      }).catch(error => {
        return reject(error)
      })
      break;
```

Comment: Are you also calling `fs.writeFile()`?  It won't change otherwise.  `fs.readFile` just reads the file into memory in your application and it exists completely separately to the file system at that point.  That's why changing it from outside your current program won't automagically change the data in your program's memory.

Comment: yes, after reading it and adding the value, I am calling the writeFile method to save my updated value.

Comment: Then I think you should add a [mre] to help us understand what is happening.  It's difficult to see the issue otherwise.

Comment: You may not we waiting for the write to finish before trying to read it again.  That's why a [mre] would help here.

Comment: Can't really help you without the relevant code.

Comment: it is an official codebase so cannot share the code here, sorry !! let me try to help you guys understand it.

Comment: @SunitS You don't need to share the code, just write us a skeleton - the statements that are immediately relevant to the question, with all potentially sensitive information abstracted away. What you're describing is most likely a code structure problem, if you show us the code structure (NOT the sensitive parts) we will be able to diagnose. Click the link [mcve] for more.

Comment: i have modified the question to accommodate the main piece of code, hope that helps.

Comment: @SunitS Thanks. We have the implementation of your file operation helper, which looks OK, as well as where you *originally* read the code, which is fine as well. Can you also share the part of code where you "read the file first and then write to it"? If there is a structural problem, it will be in there - the code giving you this problem.

Comment: @Klaycon, I have added that piece too in the question edits.

Comment: @SunitS That looks OK as well. What about the code described in "when I read it again for further modification, the earlier modified value is not there"?

Comment: @Klaycon, so here's the scenario. The 'case' and the 'fileOperation' are handled in the separate module called from the main index.js file. So, after the first successful write happens, when I read the file again in index.js, which is the second block of code, the read data does not contain the updates, it gives me the original version of the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely scenarios I can think of given what you've shared in the question:

#### 1. **Timing Issue**

It's possible that at the time that you read it again for further modification, the previous modification has yet to complete. File operations take time and are asynchronous, so if you don't handle it correctly, they can happen in an order that you don't expect.

The second code snippet you shared, in `index.js`, contains a file read. But it's not clear *when* that code runs. *When it runs* it will obtain a copy of the file as it was at that time - later updates executed by your dropdown selection will not automatically go back to the `index.js` unless you initiate another read *after* the write has completed.

#### 2. Filepath Issue

The filepaths in your code snippets are different. In one case you have `path.join(__dirname, '../../location/' + fileName)` and in another case you have `path.join(__dirname, './location/fileName')`.

It's possible that your file is writing to a location you aren't expecting. File reads and writes are done relative to [*current working directory*](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths). This means you might inadvertently be reading a different file than you're writing! Try navigating to the folder containing `index.js`, going *up* two folders, then into a `location` folder if one exists, and see if the file you're working with exists there. If it does, you'll know there's a filepath issue.

Comment: Point 2 is irrelevant as the same file is read from two different places in a hierarchy, hence the difference in the file path. However, Point 1 is I think the main issue. I completely forgot about the calls being async. Do you suggest fs.writeFileSync() ??

Comment: @SunitS "the same file is read from two different places in a hierarchy" - this is exactly the misconception I was trying to address. I'm assuming both file reads happen from the same *node.js process* - if that is true, then they are actually starting from the same place, and the paths should be identical, regardless of where the individual files are located. About the async issue - no, do not use synchronous write on a webserver, it will block your service from doing other things. You merely need to `await` or use callbacks where necessary.

Comment: If I change the file path to be the same, will not that cause issues like 'File Not Found' when I go deep into a hierarchy?

Comment: @SunitS "when I go deep into a hierarchy" - I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: ok, so here is my file structure - index.js is at the root and the json file is in a folder called 'config' and other modules in a separate folder called 'js'. Now, index.js and config are at the same level, however, the 'js' folder has got a folder called Modules and inside that, I have separate modules calling the file in the config folder.

Comment: @SunitS Sorry, you are correct due to using `__dirname`, i didn't pay attention to that. If you weren't using `__dirname` then what I was saying would be true. I would still recommend checking a folder up just to be sure it isn't a pathname issue.

Comment: the problem still persists. My modified data seems to be gone everytime. I am even having success callbacks returning the resolve but somehow somewhere something is breaking it. I will debug further and see how I can fix this.